# Is it possible to build Cutomer Support in Flutter with AR and how?

Tags: flutter, arkit, arcore

I am trying to develop a customer support page using ARCore and ARKit with Flutter. And there are 2 ARCore and ARKit plugins in `pub.dattlang.org`.

First I need to establish how to create a customer support for:

- nearest branch on map
- nearest ATM on map
- new credit offer and how to effect me if I apply etc...

Secondly I need to use ARCore and ARKit plugins to my Flutter app.

But I am not sure if the plugins will allow me to develop a customer support for my app.

***So question is: is it possible to build Customer Support with AR and how***?

Answer (score 1):

I know that if I was a customer in need of support, an augmented-reality customer support experience would not be my first choice. I would much prefer a web form where I could describe my problem in a text box. In general, customer support is going to require text entry, and handling that through augmented reality is probably a bad idea.

That being said, there are ways that you could use augmented reality to improve customer support, especially if the customer's problem has to do with the physical arrangement of objects. For example, a customer support application for IKEA might use augmented reality to display a 3D view of the customer's furniture assembling itself, to help customers who have trouble reading the 2D instructions. Or, you could have the user "paint" in AR over a 3D scene of something to indicate their problem, and then send the resulting 3D scene in to the company for the support staff to look at, which could be a higher-bandwidth form of communication than the customer trying to describe the problem by typing.

But you can't just throw arkit and arcore at the problem of "customer support"; you have to think through what the customers actually need to be supported to do, and whether and how you actually want to use AR to improve that over what you get from a simple text form. A problem like "my package didn't arrive" can't really be solved with AR. I doubt anyone else has ever used these technologies for customer support; you won't find a ready-made design here.

So that's the first step: make a list of some example customer problems for the business whose customers you are supporting, and for each of them think through whether and how AR would be useful for solving them. Once you have an idea of what AR stuff you actually want, then you can come back with a more specific question about how to achieve that using the tools at hand (arkit and arcore).

Comment: Ok, may be my example (scenario) wasnt correct one. I need to know if AR works with Flutter for a workable customer suport scenario. Like finding a nearest branch or ATM. Looking for new credit offer and how to effect me if I apply etc. Should I update my question? I need to learn if AR works with flutter with my new scanerio with this post.

Comment: You should probably update your question with an example of the sort of customer support task you want to implement. Helping the user navigate to a bank branch or ATM is a good one. If you just want to know how to do AR stuff in Flutter generally, you could maybe look at https://github.com/olexale/arkit_flutter_plugin

Comment: Well thanks I will change in 30 min, lI just need to visot the link, you just post